# Image Editor with node modules/react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron, react-bootstrap

I have started working with electron recently. There is a use case that requires me to edit an uploaded image by overlaying another image on it also changing the transparency of images and putting some text and barcodes on the edited image. Can someone suggest me a module/package that I could use to accomplish the above tasks?
I am using react and electron together.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [gm](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/), it's a native binding for GraphicsMagick / ImageMagick that should be usable in Electron. You might have to compile it with the Electorn headers in mind following the [respective part of the Electron readme](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules.md).

Comment: How will I integrate it with my React Component? How do I include gm into one of my react components ?

Comment: I don't use react, I jope someone else can chime in and help you with that. Since it's more of a follow-up, you might also create a new question that shows what you have tried so far.